# External executable can't load necessary files

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've just started messing around with Electron and for my first project I tried to make a launcher/updater for a game. My problem is that, when using "('child_process').spawn", I receive an error message of the game saying it cannot locate game files. Starting the executable without the launcher works, which means that my launcher is somehow preventing the game executable from accessing the required files.

My implementation:

buttons.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

ipcRenderer.send('play')

});
```

on main.js/createWindow:

```
ipcMain.on('play', (event) => {
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('C:\\Games\\Game\\Game.exe');
  })
```

I've tried using exec/File + Sync, which either gave the same error or didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game internal file/resource lookup is probably done in a relative manner to the game process current working directory which it assumes to be the game exe directory.

I would assume that the launcher is running from another directory, so to solve your issue you need to call `spawn` with the `cwd` option:

```
spawn('C:\\Games\\Game\\Game.exe', {cwd: 'C:\\Games\Game'});
```